# How to use python csv write the title first then write the content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a list,I want to write the list into the CSV.But first,write title.

**The list:**

> top_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

**The title:**

> title = ['col1','col2','col3']

**I want this result:**

[image]

**But now,my code's result is:**

[image]

My code:

```
import csv

top_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
title = ['col1','col2','col3']
with open(r'D:/aaa.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(top_list)
```

How to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to do it.

First use :

> writer.writerows(title)

Then use:

> writer.writerows(top_list)

Now the code can do it:

```
import csv

top_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
title = ['col1','col2','col3']
with open(r'D:/aaa.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(title)
    writer.writerows(top_list)
```